# Let bindings in do notation without layout require "in"?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell you can say

```
main = do
  let x = 5
  print x
```

and this will not compile:

```
main = do
  let x = 5
  in print x
```

But if I am using explicit layout, this does not compile:

```
main = do {
  let x = 5;
  print x;
  }
```

but this works:

```
main = do {
  let x = 5
  in print x;
  }
```

Am I right? Is there anyplace I can read more about explicit layout and do and let notation?  [Section 3.14 of the Haskell 98 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.14) seems to me to suggest that my third example should work, as it says I can write

```
do { let DECLS; stmts }
```

and it translates to

```
let DECLS in do { stmts }
```

Comment: I expect the semicolon after `5` in your third example is being parsed as part of the `let`'s block, not the `do`'s block. But I haven't looked closely enough to be sure. You might also like the Report's section on the translation from implicit to explicit blocks.

Comment: @DanielWagner you are on to something there; it does compile if I do "let {x = 5};"

Comment: Yes, the problem here comes from mixing the use of layout in the inner let with the explicit braces and semicolons in the outer do. As Daniel says, the `;` is seen as part of the declarations of the `let`, and then cannot be used to separate the declarations in the `do` anymore. I think `do { let { x = 5 }; ...` is indeed the best way to "fix" the problem. Another option is to place the `;` after `x = 5` in a place where it cannot be interpreted as part of the `let`-layout, for example in the beginning of the next line, to the left of `print x`.

Comment: @kosmikus promote comment to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normative answer to your question can be found in the Haskell report's description of the [layout rule](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3).

Briefly, you need to place a semicolon between your let block and the next statement of the do block.  That semicolon needs to lie outside of the let block.  If you *don't* use layout for the let block, that's easy, just say:

```
  let {x = 5};
```

However, if you *do* use layout for the let block, then the only way to close the let block is to start a line in a column before the column of x.  So that means you'd have to write something like this:

```
main = do {
  let x = 5
  ; print x;
}
```

Oh, and for your other example, again with layout a semicolon is getting inserted before the `in`, so your code desugars to:

```
main = do {
  let {x = 5
  };
  in print x
}
```